# Angular 4 Need to refresh page in order to show data

Tags: html, angular, frontend

I'm running in the same problem. I try to display the sex of the user inside my navbar component. I call for my service to get me the user object and then I try to set my 'gender' for use in HTML. Problem is I need to refresh the page in order to display the gender.. Any help please? :)

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {


title = 'navbar';
  userIsLoggedIn: boolean;
  user: User;
  currentUser: Parent;
  gender: string;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router, private parentService: ParentService) {
    authenticationService.userIsloggedIn.subscribe(isLoggedIn => {
      this.userIsLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
      this.user = authenticationService.getUser();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.authenticationService.getUser();
    this.userIsLoggedIn = this.user != undefined;
    this.getParentFromUserEmail(this.user.email);
    this.getSex();
  }

  private getParentFromUserEmail(email: string) {
    this.parentService.getByEmail(email).map(
      (response) => this.currentUser = response).subscribe(data => {
        this.gender = data.type;
      });
  }

  getSex() {
    return this.gender;
  }
}
```

HTML CODE

```
      <div class="sidebar-account-content">
        <h3>{{user?.firstname}} {{user?.lastname}}</h3>
        <p *ngIf="getSex()">Test</p>
        <p *ngIf="gender === 'F'">Father</p>
        <p *ngIf="gender === 'M'">Mother</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console when the page loads for the first time? Setting up code in Plunker to reproduce issue possible for you?

Comment: where are you displaying gender, i see only hard coded texts "Father" , "Mother" , "Test"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your "getUser" is a asynchronous call, therefore you not have the data of the user when call it. I suppose you must make some like

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      authenticationService.getUser().then((user)=>{
          this.user = user;
          this.userIsLoggedIn = this.user != undefined;
          this.getParentFromUserEmail(this.user.email);
          this.getSex();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create a two way binding on a method? You can just, in your template say

```
 <p *ngIf="gender">Test</p>
```

Then you can just edit the gender in your component.ts file in order to change it on the template. No need for a getter.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, I changed my return types from my service to promises. Also when our app launched we route instantly to login page since its a secure platform. The app component rendered the navbar which it shouldn't so everything from there was full of bugs. Thanks for the help, cheers.